# Is there anything like circular tweening?

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I want to implement infinite tweening of ribbon.so i want to implement using any tween like circular so that the ending of the ribbon will be followed by the starting of ribbon..please guide me..

My code is :

```
TweenMax.to(lobbyMc.contentmc, 3, { x:moveRt,overwrite:5, ease:None.easeOut,repeat : -1,startAt:{x:1000}});
```

Comment: What you have started with? any code?

Comment: yeah..i am using the repeat in tweenmax..here is the code for that


TweenMax.to(lobbyMc.contentmc, 3, { x:moveRt,overwrite:5, ease:None.easeOut,repeat : -1,startAt:{x:1000}});

Comment: You can read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096937/as3-create-a-loopable-random-path-in-3d-space/19099213#19099213 . You can create any number of 2D points and it will automatically create a looped tweening. I can adapt it to 2D space if you want, but it's a very easy task so you'll find no trouble doing it yourself